# Nexus Sonatype NPM repo does not support semver versioning

Tags: npm, nexus, sonatype, semantic-versioning

We use Nexus for our NPM packages repository (among other things). 
In our package.json files, we use semver syntax https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver
but it is ignored. Does anyone know if we have a configuration issue? Or maybe it's not something to expect from NPM over Nexus?

*Example of a scenario that can happen to us during development:*

Component A – package.json:

```
    "name": "ComponentA",
    "version": "1.1.2"
```

Component B – package.json:

```
    "name": "ComponentB",
    "version": "3.0.0"
    "dependencies": 
        "ComponentA": "^1.1.0"
```

Person1 builds & publishes version 1.1.2 of ComponentA to nexus.

a.  ComponentA  npm run build 
b.  ComponentA  npm publish to nexus
c.  npm view ComponentA  latest: 1.1.2

Now, Person2 builds 7 publishes version 1.1.1 of ComponentA to.

a.  ComponentA  npm run build 
b.  ComponentA  npm publish to nexus
c.  npm view ComponentA  latest: 1.1.1      Nexus treats the component’s latest version as the last one that was published despite knowing that 1.1.2 has been published too.

Now, when ComponentB installs its dependencies, I expect to get version 1.1.2 of ComponentA but in reality **I get version 1.1.1**.

d.  ComponentB 
     npm install

Comment: i'm getting the same problem. do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just how npm works. ^1.1.0 means use the latest version of 1.1.x - in this case it will be 1.1.1 as it marked as latest when uploaded in the order you've done.